# SQL Server Reporting Server Migration

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssrs, reporting, license

I have a separate database server and a separate reporting server. I would like to upgrade and migrate the database server to a separate server and do not to touch the reporting server. Since the reporting server License comes with the SQL server license.

Can I keep the existing reporting server and use the database server on a different license, or should I migrate both, the database and the SQL server reporting server with the same license?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You already are not using the "same license" for both servers. SSRS is part of the SQL Server license (Standard Edition and above), but it's only covered by your SQL Server license *on the same server*. IOW, if your report server is on Server A and SQL Server is on Server B, you need to license them both.

So yes, if you have acquired a license for Server B to upgrade SQL Server, you can do that without touching Server A (report server). Server A will continue to be covered by its previous license.

Verify with whomever handles your SQL Server license purchases.

Answer (score 0):

By default this is not the best place to ask about licensing questions. You should contact a Microsoft partner to get a better answer.

Said that, if you have two SQL Server licenses, you can install a new SQL Server using one license and keep the actual SSRS using the old license.

IICR, you cannot install two different SQL Server services on two different servers using the same license.

Comment: Since SSRS and database server was on a different server I guess both had separate licenses as SSRS can only be used with the same license if both SSRS and SQL server are installed on the same box..